# Change codename of worksheet with vba

Tags: excel, vba

This code works fine with VBE window open, but raises an error `Subscript out of range` at this line: `wB.VBProject.VBComponents(wS.CodeName).Properties("_CodeName").Value = "wsData"`
 when VBE window is closed.  Maybe someone can show me what I'm missing here.

```
Sub newWorkbook()
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Dim Proj As Object'<=== added

    Set wB = Workbooks.Add
    Set wS = wB.Worksheets(1)
    wS.Name = "Data"

    Set Proj = wB.VBProject '<== added
    'wB.VBProject.VBComponents(wS.CodeName).Properties("_CodeName").Value = "wsData" '<==Original line
    Proj.VBComponents(wS.CodeName).Properties("_CodeName").Value = "wsData" '<== New

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wB.SaveAs "C:\dummy.xls", 56

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If Not wB Is Nothing Then wB.Close False
    Set wB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: For the benefit of others, I've changed my post to reflect original code plus changes that resolved the problem, as inspired by @Doug Glancy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect it's a manifestation of the [two.dot rule](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/08/06/vb-net-two-dot-rule-when-working-with-office-applications-2/), or at least a distant relative. I was able to reproduce your problem. I solved it by declaring the whole chain of VBA objects, like this:

```
Sub newWorkbook()
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim vbComps As VBIDE.VBComponents
Dim vbComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim vbProps As VBIDE.Properties
Dim CodeNameProp As VBIDE.Property

Set wB = Workbooks.Add
Set wS = wB.Worksheets(1)
wS.Name = "Data"

Set vbProj = wB.VBProject
Set vbComps = vbProj.VBComponents
Set vbComp = vbComps(wS.CodeName)
Set vbProps = vbComp.Properties
Set CodeNameProp = vbProps("_Codename")
CodeNameProp.Value = "wsData"

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wB.SaveAs "E:\docs\dummy.xls", 56

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
If Not wB Is Nothing Then wB.Close False
Set wB = Nothing
End Sub
```

I had to set a reference to VBA Extensibility to do this.

Also note that the user has to have allowed access to VBA extensibility, by checking "Trust Access to the VBA Project Model" under Macro Security. You can test whether it's set like this:

```
Function ProgrammaticAccessAllowed() As Boolean
Dim vbTest As VBIDe.vbComponent

On Error Resume Next
Set vbTest = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(1)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    ProgrammaticAccessAllowed = True
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Doug, thanks for this.  Now that you pointed me in the right direction, I modified my original code slightly, mainly declaring the `vbProject` separately.  This also avoided the need to set a reference to Extensibility.

Comment: Yeah, I figured there might be an intermediate solution. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it was very helpful as I needed to change the CodeName programmatically. Using @Doug Glancy's code above as a starting point, including the ProgramatticAccessedAllowed method, I was able to create a much smaller method to create a CodeName from the Sheet Name with the spaces, dashes and periods removed.

```
    Public Function ProgrammaticAccessAllowed() As Boolean
    Dim vbTest As VBIDE.VBComponent
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vbTest = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(1)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            ProgrammaticAccessAllowed = True
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
    
    Public Sub ChangeCodeName(oSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim oProperty As Property
    Dim sCodeName As String
        With oSheet
            If ProgrammaticAccessAllowed Then
                ' Sheet name with spaces, dashes and periods removed.
                sCodeName = Replace$(Replace$(Replace$(.Name, " ", vbNullString), "-", vbNullString), ".", vbNullString)
            
                Set oProperty = .Parent.VBProject.VBComponents.Item(.CodeName).Properties.Item("_CodeName")
                ''Debug.Print oProperty.Name, oProperty.Value, sCodeName
    On Error Resume Next
                oProperty.Value = sCodeName
    On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```