# Use a variable in Objectname for WITH statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel macro which reads content from a specific column in another sheet. I want to use a variable in the sheet name in a WITH statement but keep getting an error message "Error during runtime, Object required" in the For Each line

I already searched how to use variables in object names and tried that, but to no avail.

This code works

```
With Blad2
strData = Range(id & "1") & vbLf & vbLf
    For Each c In .Range(id & "2:" & id & "10")
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            strData = strData & " - " & c.Value & vbLf
        End If
    Next c
End With
```

This code fails. I know for sure variable bld has a numeric value, tested that with MsgBox

```
With ("Blad" & bld)
strData = Range(id & "1") & vbLf & vbLf
    For Each c In .Range(id & "2:" & id & "10")
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            strData = strData & " - " & c.Value & vbLf
        End If
    Next c
End With
```

Any clues how I can get this to work?

Comment: Which line fails?

Comment: `"Blad" & bld` is a string, not an object.

Comment: As mentioned, the For Each, line 3

Comment: Hi @vincent G, that's clear so how can I use the variable bld in the objectname 'Blad2' (sheet 2 of the excel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A worksheet could be referred to in 4 ways:

- with its index;
- with its Name on the tab;
- with its `CodeName`, which is by default the same as the name of the tab, unless the latter is changed;
- with a variable;

Some time ago I have written this answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721327/5448626

---

When you write `With Blad2`, then `Blad2` is the codename of the worksheet. E.g., the one here:

[image]

Thus, it is already a variable and Excel recognizes it. On the other hand, `With ("Blad" & bld)` is a string and not a worksheet variable.

To make it work, use `With Worksheets("Blad" & bld)`, using the worksheet name of the worksheet.

Comment: Now I get an error on the line 

       With Worksheets("Blad" & bld), "the subscript is out of range"

Comment: You can't use variables for codename like this. You can use for the name of of the worksheet though :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I assume the name of the worksheet is exactly the same as the codename, as `Blad2` is the default for Dutch Excel.

Comment: @JeroenSwets - what is the value of `bld`?

Comment: The name of the worksheet as per your screenshot is `Tabelle1` :)

Comment: The value of bld = 2 and indeed its Dutch Excel so worksheet 2 name = Blad2

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I am lazy :D

Comment: Solved. I misunderstood. I had renamed the sheet. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is to use `Variable Variable` for SheetCode Name. You cannot do it like that. To achieve what you want, try this...

```
Dim bld As Long: bld = 2
Dim shtCode As String

shtCode = "Blad" & bld

With Sheets(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(shtCode).Properties("Name").Value)
    Debug.Print .Name
End With
```

Comment: Yes it works :)  File |Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings | Macro Settings | Check the checkbox "Trust access to the VBA project object model"

Comment: I do not trust it :D