# Access sub in a sheet when workbook is closed

Tags: excel, vba

I want that whenever the workbook is closed a Sub from a sheet(sheet13) should be called, but as shown in the screenshot Im getting the error Invalid or unqualified reference.
By now I have tried

```
  B2_Click

  !Sheets("sheet13").B2_click

  !Sheets("Employee Names").B2_click

  Thisworkbook.Sheets("Employee Names").B2_click
```

And I am getting an error every time.

[image]

Comment: Simply `Sheet13.B2_click` if your B2_click is `Public` and doesn't need parameters ...

Answer (score 1):

Your last example should work, so I would direct my troubleshooting towards the method you are calling. Try this in a new workbook:
In ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet13").Test
End Sub
```

And in Sheet13 module

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox "Closing"
End Sub
```

If that works, you have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the easy solution as already mentioned by others:
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("January").Something` (string is case sensitive!)

There are multiple ways to reference a Sheet, and there are different types of names for worksheets. You have to differentiate between the "CodeName" and the "Name".
You will easily find more information on the difference between those two.

The main differences are, that the `Name` can be changed by the user, it is the name visible on the tab at the bottom of the Excel Interface.
The `CodeName` can only be changed through the VBA Interface.
The `CodeName` and the `Name` are usually identical when creating a worksheet (Sheet1, etc..).

To Reference a Sheet by Name you can use this code:
`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SomeName").SomeFunction()`
The `CodeName` can be used directly like this: `Sheet2.SomeFunction()`, but I'd recommend changing the CodeName to something meaningful/expressive first!

`(Name)` is the CodeName, `Name` is the visible Name
[image: Properties Sheet Example]

More information on the Bang operator `!` can be found here:
https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/03/15/vba-trap-default-members/

Extensive Answer on referencing Sheets:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/10223558