# I keep assigning a value to my variable but it stays empty

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a code that is supposed to assign a value to a certain variable and open a file with the name assigned to the variable.
However, every time I debug the code, VBA warns me that no value is assigned to the variable even though the file is successfully opened. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub StressTest()

Dim index As Integer
Dim dateColumn As Integer
Dim portfolioName As Variant
Dim portfolioDate As String
Dim ParametricVar As Double
Dim AuM As Double


portfolioDate = InputBox("Please enter date under the following form : YYYY-MM", "Date at the time of Stress Test", "Type Here")


For index = 3 To 32

portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & index & "").Value

'Error happens on this line vvv
Workbooks.Open "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

ParametricVar = Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("B19")

AuM = Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("Holdings - Main View").Range("E11")




Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = ParametricVar / AuM
Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn + 2).Value = ParametricVar / AuM

Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn + 5).Value = Application.Min(Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("P11:AA11"))
Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn + 6).Value = Application.Max(Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("J16:J1000"))


Next index




End Sub
```

Comment: at what line do you get error message? Have you switched on `Option Explicit`?

Comment: You can set the results of `Workbooks.Open` to a workbook variable, and use that to simplify the subsequent code.

Comment: The error appears on the line : 
Workbooks.Open "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch on the `Option Explicit` setting, like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement).

In this case  you'll notice, that *variable `Sheet1` is not declared, though it is used*. You need either to:

- declare this variable
- or use `ActiveSheet`, `Worksheets("Sheet1")` instead of `Sheet1`
- or use `Sheet1` codename reference in your language, e.g. for Russian:

[image]

where highlighted `Лист1` is used instead of `Sheet1`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477794/refer-to-sheet-using-codename), specifically number 3.

Comment: Yes, I've understood. I've got localized version of MS Excel, so CodeName of mine is another language

Comment: Even if it isn't recommended, `Sheet1.` is unlikely to be the problem. For one thing, OP is explicitly referring to the value of one of their variables and they are not thinking about `Sheet1` as a variable at all (since it isn't, really).  `Option Explicit` is a good recommendation.

Comment: He may have localized version of MS Excel, as in my case, so that would be obstacle

Comment: See the latest [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737201/i-keep-assigning-a-value-to-my-variable-but-it-stays-empty#comment100033642_56737201) on which line throws the error. It has nothing to do with `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

Transform your code to this, and study immediate window (`Ctrl` + `G` in VBA editor) to see if generated file path is correct.

```vb
Sub StressTest()

Dim index As Integer
Dim dateColumn As Integer
Dim portfolioName As Variant
Dim portfolioDate As String
Dim ParametricVar As Double
Dim AuM As Double
Dim strPath As String


portfolioDate = InputBox("Please enter date under the following form : YYYY-MM", "Date at the time of Stress Test")
Debug.Print "InputBox provided value is: " & portfolioDate 


For index = 3 To 32

portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & index & "").Value
Debug.Print "ActiveSheet Name is: " & ActiveSheet.Name
Debug.Print "portfolioName value is: " & portfolioName 
Dim strFilePath As String
strPath =  "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""
Debug.Print strPath
Workbooks.Open strPath

ParametricVar = Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("B19")

AuM = Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("Holdings - Main View").Range("E11")




Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = ParametricVar / AuM
Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn + 2).Value = ParametricVar / AuM

Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn + 5).Value = Application.Min(Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("P11:AA11"))
Sheet1.Cells(index, dateColumn + 6).Value = Application.Max(Workbooks("" & portfolioName & "").Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("J16:J1000"))


Next index
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it still gives me the same error on the line: 
Workbooks.Open StrPath

Comment: The problem is with the portfolioDate variable, it isn't taking the value I am trying to assign to it. It says that it is empty even though the file is successfully opening

Comment: And what do you get immediate window? Check this path, because error seems to be in this string concatenating?

Comment: Updated code, you can try to run it again and see what value is used further (in immediate). Other point is that I've removed default value for inputbox.

Comment: `strFilePath` is empty because you've assigned to `strPath`, not `strFilePath`, but you don't use `strFilePath`. Again, `Option Explicit` will prevent this possible source of error. `portfolioDate` is *definitely* not empty unless you cancel the InputBox. I don't think it is necessary to enclose `portfolioName` in escaped double quotes. try `Workbooks(portfolioName)` isntead.

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected the code but I still have the same error on the same line. portfolioName is still empty.

Comment: Updated code. You are using `ActiveSheet` reference, I think you are addressing sheet, that contains nothing in desired cell. Check what ActiveSheet name you are addressing through studying immediate window

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,
In the very simple script bellow, the value in 'Locals' is empty but it is surely not since the print to 'Immediate' does return the path!!!

```
Sub ChooseZipFile()

Dim fullpath As String
'Choose ZIP file
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Name of Window
        .Title = "Please Select Zip File"
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "ZIP File", "*.zip; *.TGZ", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show
        
        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Debug.Print fullpath
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is a question for which you did not find an answer, then issue it separately as an independent problem.