# While debugging VBA code, i am getting an erorr saying "Object required for the 8th line

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub copyNonblankData()

Dim erow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
    ' i'm assuming the next line is the 8th line?
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ' error occurs here
    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row.Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 2))
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)).Copy` - you didnt qualify your cells references.

Comment: Yes, I do have Sheet1

Comment: I am getting error in line, "erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row.Offset(1, 0).Row". Where i have already define "erow" as long

Comment: Maybe not worth an answer below, but do you really need to transfer these values through copy/paste? You can immediately transfer values without using clipboard functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The Offset property in Excel VBA **takes the range** which is a particular number of rows and columns away from a certain range.

`Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will give you `Long` and not a `Range Object`.

Your code can be written as

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

erow = rng.Row
```

Or simply as

```
erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Also your code will work if the relevant sheet is active. You need to fully qualify your cells as shown in [Why does Range work, but not Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733541/why-does-range-work-but-not-cells)

**TIP**

If you are using `CodeName` then use `CodeName` and avoid using the `Name` of the sheet. And if you are using `Name` then avoid using `Codename`. You will end up getting confused. If you do not know the difference between them, then you may want to see [Refer to sheet using codename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477794/refer-to-sheet-using-codename)

Remember you will get the same error (`Object required`) again if the **Codename** doesn't exist. BTW if the **Name** of the sheet doesn't exist then you will get a different error (`Subscript Out Of Range`).

so if `erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` gives the same error then that means `Sheet2` doesn't exist. Try with

```
erow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned code but i am getting the same error and i verified my both sheets are active.

Comment: did you replace `erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row.Offset(1, 0).Row` with `erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Yes, i did it both the ways

Comment: I have updated the post. you may have to refresh the page to see it