# How can I protect sheet when code fails due to VBA error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with many routines, sometimes they fail and I research the issue and fix it. BUt when a routine fails the code never finishes and sometimes it leaves my sheet unprotected. 
Is there a way to protect a sheet in the event of a VBA error?

Comment: Look for: on error handler

Comment: I am not sure, I am not an expert coder, just use what little knowledge I have to help automate my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code's comments and adjust it to include your code

```
Public Sub TestErrAndProtect()

' This line tells what to do and where to go when an error is raised
On Error GoTo CleanFail

    ' Your code goes here


CleanExit:
    ' Adjust ActiveSheet to the codename of the sheet if needed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721327/1521579)
    ActiveSheet.Protect
    ' This line tells the program to exit the procedure
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    ' This line shows the error description in a message box
    MsgBox Err.Description
    ' This line tells the program to go to a label
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works and remember to mark the answer if it does.

Comment: Can I put this somewhere will it is global and will execute on any VBA error or do I have to put it in each sub routine?

Comment: You have to put it in each `Sub`

Comment: The starting part of your code says Public, do I place this under each Private sub

Comment: Nope. This was just an example. Your subs may be Private (doesn't matter).  Begin with `On Error...` before your code. And after your code and before `End Sub` place `CleanExit...`