# Is there a way to retrieve the codename of an Excel sheet in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm working with a template where sheet names might change, but codenames will not.
Is there a way to retrieve the codename of an Excel sheet in C#?

`shCodeName = SH_parent.CodeName;` does not seem to work, although `shName = SH_parent.Name;` works just fine

//Definition of SH_parent
`Excel.Worksheet SH_parent;`

//Loading SH_parent

```
            foreach (Excel.Name N in WB.Names)
            {
                if (!N.Name.Contains("!"))
                {
                    //GLOBAL
                    string SH_Name = N.RefersTo.ToString().Split('!')[0].Replace("=", "").Replace("'", "");
                    SH_parent= WB.Worksheets[SH_Name];
                }
                else
                {
                    //SHEET
                    SH_parent = N.Parent;
                }
```

Comment: msdn seems to say yes - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename

Comment: Is SH_parent a worksheet object? are you getting an error?

Comment: or here seems to work aswell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477794/refer-to-sheet-using-codename

Comment: for VB it does work, but i'm looking for a C# alternative. SH_parent is an Excel.Worksheet object. I will update how I load it in the main question.