# Using a variable within a worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a set of worksheets to automate a copy and paste process in Excel VBA.

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & counter).Activate` throws an error.

The `counter` variable should run from 9 to 11.

I indicated the line that is giving me troubles with asterisks in a comment.

```vb
Sub copy_pm_forecast()

Dim counter, row, col, newRow, yearColBeg, yearColEnd As Integer
Dim foundRow, foundCol, foundYearBeg, foundYearEnd As Range
Dim currentSheet As String

counter = 9

Do
    currentSheet = "Sheet" & counter
    
    'this block activates the sheet that corresponds to the index indicated by variable "counter" and finds the correct row the "Actuals/COF" values
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(currentSheet).Activate '**

    Set foundRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100").Find("Actuals/COF")
    row = foundRow.row
    
    'this block finds the columns in which the beginning month of the fiscal year and year total reside
    Set foundYearBeg = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100").Find("July")
    yearColBeg = foundYearBeg.Column
    Set foundYearEnd = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100").Find("TOTAL", MatchCase:=True)
    yearColEnd = foundYearEnd.Column
    
    'this block copies and pastes the values from row to row + 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(currentSheet)
        .Range(Cells(row, yearColBeg), Cells(row, yearColEnd)).Copy
        .Range(Cells(row + 1, yearColBeg), Cells(row + 1, yearColEnd)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    'this block finds the proper column and row to which to paste the total values
    Set foundCol = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z100").Find("Prior COF")
    col = foundCol.Column
    newRow = foundCol.row
    
    'this block copies and pastes the values from the "Total" column to the "Prior COF" column
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(counter)
        .Range(Cells(newRow + 2, yearColEnd), Cells(row + 1, yearColEnd)).Copy
        .Range(Cells(newRow + 2, col), Cells(row + 1, col)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    
    'increments "counter" by one so that the next worksheet is selected when the loop iterates again
    counter = counter + 1

Loop Until counter = 12

End Sub
```

I tried using the index number.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(counter).Activate
```

This works - however, the problem with just using the index is that I want to add or shuffle worksheets without any adverse affects to the output of the code.

I tried to isolate the problem by removing the variable.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet9").Activate
```

This is still throwing the error.

Comment: If `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet9").Activate` gives an error (FYI it really helps to tell us which specific error) then either there's no sheet with that name in the workbook where your code is running, or perhaps it's a hidden sheet.

Comment: FYI this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba is a go-to post here: it will explain why selecting a sheet and then using `ActiveSheet` should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for getting back to me so fast, and for sharing the link to the post re: `ActiveSheet`. I'll look into that. The error that is being thrown is Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. I was looking for a way to upload the Excel spreadsheet I'm referencing, but I didn't see a way to do that. Sheet9 does exist, but maybe I'm not entering in the information in the correct way to reference it?

Comment: That error indicates there's no sheet with tab name "Sheet9" in the workbook.  Is the sheet you want in the same workbook where your code is running?  Is the tab name actually "Sheet9" ?  Note worksheets also have a `CodeName` which is visible in the VBA editor project tree.   If `Sheet9` is the codename then you can refer to it just as `Sheet9` ie. `Sheet9.Activate`    See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/478884

Comment: Ah ok, so you are correct. I was trying to refer to the `CodeName` of the worksheet which is `Sheet9`, but was using the syntax to refer to the actual name. Is there a way to concatenate a variable with part of the code name? I.e. can I write the code `Sheet & counter`? I wrote that exact code and it didn't work, but it is an example of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to refer to a worksheet given the workbook and the sheet's codename:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = WorksheetSheetFromCodeName(ThisWorkbook, "Sheet" & "8")
    Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.CodeName
End Sub


Function WorksheetSheetFromCodeName(wb As Workbook, codeNm As String)
    Dim ws
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets      'loop all worksheets in `wb`
        If ws.CodeName = codeNm Then  'got a match on CodeName?
            Set WorksheetSheetFromCodeName = ws  'return sheet reference
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

Then inside your loop use (eg)  `ws.Range(...)`, `ws.Cells(...)` instead of just `Range()` or `Cells()`

Comment: Than you very much, Tim!