How can I Reference Worksheets by CodeName
How do you reference a Worksheet by its CodeName rather than its (Tab) Name?
I have tried:
Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CodeName")


Dim wsn As String

        wsn = ActiveSheet.CodeName


And various other methods of which I no longer have,
due to the fact I delete code that does not work.
I have seen a number of solutions to this problem that seem unnecessarily long and/or hard to understand.
What I am looking for is a short concise answer (one line of code would be nice).
Something easy to understand and/or well commented.

You may have a look onto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41477794/17172829

I have spoken about it in Sheets and Worksheets and how to reference them. feel free to have a look.

In short: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("CodeName").Properties("Name").Value). But since you're in the workbook containing this code (ThisWorkbook), you can simplify with Set ws = CodeName or use CodeName instead of ws (replace CodeName with the actual code name).

If you remove the comment lines it really is quite short, and if you remove the error checking it is essentially one line of code.
    'This Function converts a worksheet's code name to its (Tab) name,
    'which circumvents errors occurring in the event
    'the Worksheets tab name has being changed.
    'Original code by me, Quartz_au.
    Public Function NameFromCodeName(ByVal inCodeName As String) As String
    
        On Error GoTo CanNotFind
        
        'One line of code to assign NameFromCodeName the worksheet's (Tab) Name.
        NameFromCodeName = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(inCodeName) _
                           .Properties("Name").Value
        
        GoTo ExitHere
    CanNotFind:
        MsgBox "No Worksheet exists with the Code Name: """ & inCodeName & """" _
               & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Step through code to locate the call." _
               , vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Get Worksheet Name Error"
        Stop 'Step through code to locate the call that triggered the error.
        
    ExitHere:
        On Error GoTo 0
    End Function 'NameFromCodeName

'################################# TESTER #################################
Private Sub TEST_NameFromCodeName()
Dim wsn As String, _
    cn  As String

    'Use a valid CodeName here.
    cn = "Data_Vi"
    wsn = NameFromCodeName(cn)
    
    MsgBox "Worksheet Name: """ & wsn & """" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) _
           & "Entered Code Name: """ & cn & """" _
           , vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Name From CodeName TEST"
    
    'Use a invalid CodeName here.
    wsn = NameFromCodeName("I_ERROR")
    
End Sub 'TEST_NameFromCodeName
'################################# TESTER #################################


Thank you VBasic2008 it seems you had the answer all along. And I thought I was so clever.

Note that for this you need to have enable "Trust access to the VBA project object model" in the Excel Trust Center - which is often blocked in corporate environments.

Thank you FunThomus. I could not find or know how to do this. However I fiddled with the code and got it working and wrote a macro to add worksheets that will allow me to add my own CodeNames to them.
